# How to get @EnableWebMvc to work with Thymeleaf and SpringBoot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, thymeleaf

i am trying to use `@ResponseBody` to send Json from my controller but i read that for it to work i need to add the `org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl` dependency and also add `@EnableWebMvc` annotation. Anytime i enable the `@EnableWebMvc` it breaks Springboot auto configuration and my resource directory is unable to be reached. At the moment ajax is not able to read the variable errorMessageList i set in my controller

Comment: None of that is necessary to make it work as long as you use the appropriate spring-boot-starters. Consider initializing your project with spring initializr to line up all your dependencies for you.

Comment: You don't need any of those. Json marshaling should just work.

Comment: @CollinD What do i do if Ajax is not able to read variables in my controller or pojo

Comment: Show some code. It's not clear what variables or pojo you are talking about.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve].